# Type casting a shape into a component in Java?

Tags: java, types, casting, components, shapes

How can I type cast a shape (like a rounded rectangle) into a component?

Comment: I don't think the question makes sense... or at least I don't understand it.

Comment: You can PAINT a shape on a component (like a JPanel)...

Comment: @LazyCubicleMonkey Yes, I understand that. What I want is to add an event listener to a shape. That is, when a shape is clicked upon, I want to execute certain code. As far as I know, you can only add listeners to components. That is why I would like to type cast shapes into components. Someone mentioned the phrase "Custom Component" to me, but I can't find that class in the Java library. Perhaps it is a method somewhere. At any rate, I can just set the listener to the JPanel that holds those shapes, get the x and y coordinates when the mouse is clicked, and check to see if it is in the shape

Answer (score 1):

Casting is simply changing a reference of an object to a different representation, not converting and object to an object of a different type.

Giving an example with some made up classes, you can cast a Shape to a Square, iff that Shape already actually is a Square:

```
Shape shape = new Square();
Square square = (Square) s; // this will be okay!
```

This is just exposing existing extra behaviour of the object associated with it's being a square, not converting it to a square. You can't do this, for example:

```
Shape shape = new Square();
Circle circle = (Circle) shape; // this will throw a ClassCastException
```

Because the shape is not actually a circle to begin with, and you would be potentially exposing behaviours (e.g. getPerimeter()) which would not actually make sense for the underlying object.

Similarly, in your case, a Shape is not a Component and it never will be, so you cannot cast it to be one. You cannot perform a cast to expose behaviour related to Components (adding listeners) because this behaviour is not supported by the Shape class. The shape class will not receive event messages from the interface even if it did make sense to add a listener to it, because it has not been added to the interface as a Component to begin with. Presumably you are painting the shapes onto a component manually, so you should already understand that they are not a part of the component hierarchy.

As you suggested, the best way to deal with this presuming you have already got to the point where the shapes are drawn inside a component, would be by manually checking that the x and y coordinates of the relevant MouseEvent are inside each Shape.

If you wanted to treat them as Components from the start, you would have to create Components for each shape, and add them to a Container using a LayoutManager, the same way you build the rest of the interface. This would involve creating a "custom Component" as you said, which rather than being the name a class or method which is ready to use, means to create your own sub-class of Component which could, perhaps, take a Shape argument in it's constructor. [Here is an example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/506289/GUI/java/custom-shaped-gui-components) I found for creating a custom button Component which is round, which with some modification should meet your needs.

You basically answered your own question for the most part in your last comment, this hopefully will help you understand how :).

Cheers, hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

From your further feedback I understand you just want to create a custom component.

Now the tricky question is: do you really want/need a custom component?

Normally you will only need extend the shape class and implement/override the contains() (, other methods that you require) and paint() methods where you draw what you want.

The listener can then be set within the container class (JFame,JPanel,..) that you use to place the shape and by using the shape.contains(point) you can handle events on it.

If you really need a component the major advantage is that they can handle events, interact with other components and also with layouts managers.

You can check [this](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=119370) example on that.